# Serilog.Sinks.MsSqlServer stops writing to database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, serilog

I'm using:

- Asp.Net Core 2.2.0
- Serilog 2.9.0
- Serilog.AspNetCore 3.2.0
- Serilog.Sinks.MsSqlServer 5.1.3

I'm configuring Serilog in `appsettings.json` :

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;",
          "schemaName": "MySchema",
          "tableName": "Log",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": "true"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": ".\\Logs\\MyApp.log",
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

In my `Program.cs` :

```
var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
                 loggerConfiguration
                .ReadFrom
                .Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration))
    .Build();

Log.Information("Starting application ...");
```

I see this initial log written to both file and database.

But subsequent `Log.Information()` statements executed in the course of processing a web request ( entry point `Controller HttpPost` ) are written only to file -- not to database.

There is nothing in my code to change `Serilog` config. I don't see why initial log would be written to database but not subsequent.

I've configured self-log

```
SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
```

but Serilog is not throwing any exceptions ( or at least it's not writing them to debug output ).

Comment: `initial log would be written to database but not subsequent.` I did a test on my side, can not reproduce same issue, the log(s) can be wirtten to db well. If possible, please share the code of your Program.cs that is used to configure Serilog, so that we can troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: I've updated my post.  I have the same issue when I configure `Serilog` entirely in `Program.cs`